# Join by part of string

Tags: mysql, join

I have following tables:

```
**visitors**
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| visitors_id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| visitors_path       | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

**fedora_info**
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid            | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| owner_uid      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

First I looking for `visitors_path` that are related to specific pages by:

```
SELECT visitors_id, visitors_path
FROM visitors
WHERE visitors_path REGEXP '[[:<:]]fedora/repository/.*:[0-9]+$';
```

The above query return expected result.

now `.*:[0-9]+` in above query referred to `pid` in second table. now I want know count of result in above query grouped by `owner_uid` in second table.

How can I JOIN this tables?

**EDIT**

sample data:

```
visitors
+-------------+---------------------------------+
| visitors_id | visitors_path                   |
+-------------+---------------------------------+
|        4574 | fedora/repository/islandora:123 |
|        4575 | fedora/repository/islandora:123 |
|        4580 | fedora/repository/islandora:321 |
|        4681 | fedora/repository/islandora:321 |
|        4682 | fedora/repository/islandora:321 |
|        4704 | fedora/repository/islandora:321 |
|        4706 | fedora/repository/islandora:456 |
|        4741 | fedora/repository/islandora:456 |
|        4743 | fedora/repository/islandora:789 |
|        4769 | fedora/repository/islandora:789 |
+-------------+---------------------------------+

fedora_info
+-----------------+-----------+
| pid             | owner_uid |
+-----------------+-----------+
| islandora:123   |         1 |
| islandora:321   |         2 |
| islandora:456   |         3 |
| islandora:789   |         4 |
+-----------------+-----------+

Expected result:
+-----------------+-----------+
| count           | owner_uid |
+-----------------+-----------+
| 2               |         1 |
| 4               |         2 |
| 3               |         3 |
| 2               |         4 |
| 0               |         5 |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please give the expected result of your sample data. They should match

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im question updated ;)

Comment: Did you see my last update? It works. If it works for you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to **normalize your database**. When inserting rows in `visitors` extract `pid` in the front end language and put it in a separate column (e.g. `fi_pid`). Then you can join it easily.

The following query might work for you. But it'll be little cpu intensive.

```
SELECT 
       COUNT(a.visitors_id) as `count`,
       f.owner_uid
FROM   (SELECT visitors_id, 
               visitors_path, 
               SUBSTRING(visitors_path, ( LENGTH(visitors_path) - 
                                          LOCATE('/', REVERSE(visitors_path)) ) 
                                        + 2) AS 
                      pid 
        FROM   visitors 
        WHERE  visitors_path REGEXP '[[:<:]]fedora/repository/.*:[0-9]+$') AS `a`

JOIN fedora_info AS f 
         ON ( a.pid = f.pid ) 

GROUP  BY f.owner_uid
```

Comment: `.*:[0-9]+` can be like `islandora:1234` or `default:123456`

Comment: Thanks, but it returned empty result

Comment: Tune it please. Show sample data and sample expected result

Comment: also `pid` is like `islandora:1234` or `default:123456`

Comment: return Error: `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM (SELECT visitors_id, visitors_path, SU' at line 1`

Comment: Your query works and `Query took 6.6111 sec` very better from mine ;) thanks, I will use yours.

Comment: If you would have normalized the database it'd take less than `0.1` sec.

Answer (score 0):

Following query returns expected result, but its very slow `Query took 9.6700 sec`

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.pid), t1.owner_uid
FROM fedora_info t1
JOIN (SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'fedora/repository/' FROM visitors_path) as pid
FROM visitors
WHERE visitors_path REGEXP '[[:<:]]fedora/repository/.*:[0-9]+$') t2 ON t1.pid = t2.pid
GROUP BY t1.owner_uid
```